# How to tokenize phrases

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

I am currently working on a classfication task using Tensorflow NLP. I want to tokenize the list of texts but for phrases not for each individual words. Below is a simple example

```
input = ['I am', 'I do', 'I', 'I am']
```

I want to output

```
output = [1,2,3,1]
```

Thank you

Best,
DD

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to assign each word/phrase a number.

```
input = ['I am', 'I do', 'I', 'I am']
output = [input.index(word)+1 for word in input]
print(output)  # [1, 2, 3, 1]
```